# Help evaluating a multivariable limit

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I tried approaching from y=0, from x=0, from x=y, I also tried using polar coordinates, I always get 0/0. What do I need to do to?

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} \dfrac{(x-y)(x+y-2)}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}}$$

[Mulivariable limit problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EHcj.png)

Comment: If $y=x$ this is $\frac{0}{\sqrt{2(x-1)^2}} = 0$ which has a limit of $0$ as $x \to 1$; if  $y=1$ this is $|x-1|$ which has a limit of $0$ as $x \to 1$;  if  $x=1$ this is $-|y-1|$ which has a limit of $0$ as $y \to 1$.  That is not a proof, but it does suggest the limit at $(1,1)$ may be $0$

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Set $x=1+r\cos\theta, y=1+r\sin \theta$ and do some trigonometry.

Comment: @Bernard could you expand please? I got down to lim [r->1]  ((cos+sin)^2)/sqrt(1) and stuck

Answer (score 4):

With the change of variable $u=x-1$, $v=y-1$, we are to compute $\lim_{(u,v)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{(u-v)(u+v)}{\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}$.

Note that
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{(u-v)(u+v)}{\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}\right|\leq|u|\cdot\dfrac{|u|}{\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}+|v|\cdot\dfrac{|v|}{\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}\leq|u|+|v|\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=1+r\cos\theta$, $y=1+\sin\theta$. You obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{(x-y)(x+y-2)}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}}&=\frac{(r\cos\theta-r\sin\theta)(r\cos\theta+r\sin\theta)}{\sqrt{r^2}}\\&=r(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)=r\cos2\theta,
\end{align}
which tends to $0$ as $r$ tends to $0$.

Comment: +1 nice solution Bernard.